# Suppress exception in Wildfly log

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-10

I want some Exceptions to not appear in the server's console log.

I tried to set a filter in `standalone.xml` but the exception still shows up.

```
<console-handler name="CONSOLE">
   <level name="INFO"/>
   <filter-spec value="not(match(&quot;.*java.lang.RuntimeException.*&quot;))" />
   <formatter>
         <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
   </formatter>
 </console-handler>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately at this point messages cannot be filtered by the exception. Only the message being logged can be filtered. There is a [JIRA](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/LOGMGR-86) to create an exception filter.

If you just don't want to see exceptions on the console you could remove the `%e` or `%E` from the format pattern and then only look for exceptions in the `server.log`.